# no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer when I am trying to do a for loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, for-loop, hash

I am trying to use for loop to show more images on one page.

I have tried

```
 <% @products.each do |product| %>
         <div class="col-xs-3">
          <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/96974/pexels-photo-96974.jpeg?h=350&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb" alt="...">
              <div class="caption">
              <h3><%= product[:name] %></h3>
              <p><%= product[:description] %></p>
              <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
<% end %>
```

It is my home controller which I add below:
class HomeController < ApplicationController

```
  def index
    @ad = {
        title: "大型广告",
        des: "这是广告",
        action_title: "这是广告",
    }
    @products = {
        id: "1",
        name: "柳橙汁",
        description: "好喝的柳橙汁",
        image_url: "https://images.pexels.com/photos/96974/pexels-photo-96974.jpeg?h=350&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb",
    }
  end
end
```

It shows no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer.

Comment: Post error back-trace here

Comment: what contains in @products? is it collection or array?

Comment: What is `@products`? What does it return?

Comment: Please add the code that assigns `@products` (probably your controller action).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `@products` is a query Ex. `@products = Product.all`

You can use `product.name` instead of [:name]

Comment: `product.name`, `product['name']` & `product[:name]` all these deliver same for your information.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on your (now deleted) comment:

> After I tried your solution<sup>†</sup>, it says `` undefined method `name' for [:id, "1"]:Array ``
>
> ---
>
> <sup>†</sup> using `product.name` instead of `product[:name]`

Your `@products` array contains other 2-element arrays like this:

```
@products = [[:id, "1"], [:id, "2"], [:id, "3"]]
```

Therefore each `product` refers to one of these inner arrays and `product[:name]` results in the error message:

```
product = @products.first
#=> [:id, "1"]

product[:name]
# TypeError (no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer)
```

You solve this problem by changing what's inside the `@products` array. It should be instances of `Product`, not other arrays. The assignment probably occurs in your controller.